# Why does Array.reduce have to return a subclass?

Tags: kotlin

If I'm reading the type signature correctly, `Array.reduce` has to return a subclass of the type of the item in the array? That seems like a totally arbitrary and unnecessary restriction?

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Array<out T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

[source](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html)

Why can't it be an arbitrary class like:

```
fun main(params: Array<String>) {
  val args = params.reduce(Args(), {accum: Args, arg: String -> accum.parse(arg) })
}
```

Comment: As you can see you had to add an extra argument to your "more general" `reduce` function. This general function exists and is called `fold` in Kotlin, and doesn't have the type limitation you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is the opposite: return type has to be a supertype of the data in the array, not a subtype. I don't think it has anything to do with mutability.

The reason is that in the first iteration the first item in the array becomes the accumulator. So if the array would contain e.g. integers, but accumulator would be of `String` type, this first step would not be possible.

`fold()` works differently: it receives initial value of the accumulator as a parameter, so it can be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Array.reduce` is non-mutating reduction. For mutating reduction, you want [`Array.fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) instead.

Comment: You could write a mutating `reduce` and a non-mutating `fold` - it doesn't have anything to do with mutation, it has to do with exactly what the OP is mentioning: fold has a more general return type and doesn't need the collection to be non-empty, and it does that by asking for an initial accumulator value.

Comment: @Joffrey  I'm using the term "mutable reduction" in the sense that it's used in [Java's Collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) documentation. Kotlin calls it fold instead. That's fine, just made it hard to find as someone with Java background. Hence I figured I'd drop something on SO for people to find.